# Why do humans feel compassion towards non-humans?

Tags: evolution, evolutionary-psychology, moral-psychology

Why is it that humans feel compassion towards non-humans, such as animals? For me, the sight of an injured bird causes an emotional response, but I cannot explain what would cause it. From an evolutionary standpoint, I can't think what advantage compassion towards "prey" would bring for survival.

Comment: Not only humans have proved to have this ability, and not all humans have it.

Comment: See the literature on "mind perception" (e.g., Wegner, Gray).